# Can I set the onboard keyboard in a different language than my system language?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, onboard

I am moving to China and I'll need an **onboard** keypad with character prediction in Chinese. I want to keep my physical keyboard set to English, but I'll need an onboard Chinese keyboard on my screen too.

It should come with word prediction if such thing exists in Ubuntu. I have no clue how to write chinese characters, but I know how to write pinyin a bit...so word prediction could help me a lot. 
I have been using this trick with my Android devices (using pinyin to get the Chinese characters from the prediction).

Is this something I could do in Ubuntu too for writing emails and in documents?

Comment: AFAIK the layout of the onboard keyboard follows the current keyboard layout for the session. I don't speak Chinese, but I have the impression that the tools for inputting Chinese characters are often used with the English (US) keyboard layout.

Comment: Pinyin on computers is the same as on Android - you type in pinyin and sets of characters show up to choose from. In addition, pinyin usually allows you switching from English to Chinese and vice versa by single clicking "Shift" key.  I'm sure what you ask for can be scripted, but . . . there's really no need for that. Just practice more with pinyin. Also, congrats on moving to China ! I'm quite envious :)

Comment: I am using swift keyboard with android and it gives instant prediction on Chinese characters from pinyin. This is what I'd like to achieve in Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the language of your keyboard via the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

You can also check this page of mine, where I've provided some more details:

- [Ubuntu Keyboard Configuration](http://lookingforawebsitedesigner.online/how-to-addchange-keyboard-language-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: I have just updated my question. Cheers.